# How can I send Current web page's whole HTML document to server?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

how can I send my currently seeing web page(means javascript processed manipulated html documnet for user's view - kind of interactive AJAX web pages) to server?

Can I send 'the documnet object mother of all html elements' to server as it is?

Comment: Your question should be more specific about what you are trying to achieve but you can get all the markup if you have jquery http://jsfiddle.net/MUkGe/ but I don't actually see purpose for this.

Comment: You can get everything between the `<html></html>` tags by using `document.documentElement.innerHTML`.

Comment: Oh Holy GODs! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use standard js function for getting 'body' element and it's innerHTML

```
  var bodyHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```

then you can use ajax request to a server for sending html

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
     <style type="text/css">
         .contain-entire-page {
             display: none;
         }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- us\sonawpa -->
    <form class="submit-entire-page" action="demo.php" method="post">
        <textarea class="contain-entire-page"></textarea>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var str = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
            str += $('html').html();
            str += '</html>';
            $('.contain-entire-page').val(str);
            $('.submit-entire-page').submit();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to interact with web server inside a web page, you can submit a form (POST a web request to an web application) or request a URL (GET a web request from an URL).

If you want to send something to server, you can POST the parameters you want, and when server get the request, it will perform some functions and give you a response.
Sample of POST:

```
    POST www.xxxx.com?name=asdf HTTP/1.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 97
    Host: www.xxxx.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

the response is:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: application/json
    Cache-Control: no-store
    Pragma: no-cache
    Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2013 08:04:29 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    <html><body>Hello World</body></html>
```

Hope this help.